# Need advice about VCR to PC connection

Tags: video-capture, usb

I need advice for something I want to do with VCR to PC image transfering. I have bought a video capture usb (RCA to usb) but there is a problem with the image... It's shaking right and left.
Like this

Firstly, let me tell you that when I connect the VCR to the TV the image is fine. Also when I connect a DVD player (a device way newer than the VCR) to the PC through the same usb, the image is also fine. So, something must be wrong when the analog-to-digital signal converting is happening. It's like the TV sees this problematic image and has a way to fix it somehow. On the other hand, the usb doesn't have a way to fix it, so I have this shaking image.

So, my question is:

What are the possible explanations/causes for this? Usb device quality? VCR quality? What system has a TV to fix a VCR shaking image?? Is there a software or some settings for PC that do the same fix a TV does?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost definitely with the tape or the VCR. Most likely the sync or black level is off or [the control track is fluttering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMA5aH_olAQ), which is throwing off the ADC in the capture dongle. You will need a [time base corrector (TBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_base_correction) or [frame synchronizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_synchronization_(video)) to correct the problem.

Ideally, you should also have a way to view and adjust the video levels. Usually you can adjust levels with a good quality TBC or FS. You can use software to view a waveform and vectorscope after digitization.

Comment: It must be the VCR, because every tape does the same. Thanks for the explanation, even though I don't know much about waveforms and I don't know if I would understand what I would see. :P